# How to create a file with 777 rights in nodejs

Tags: node.js

how to create a file with 777 rights in nodejs correctly?

I'm trying to do this:

```
fs.createWriteStream(filename, {mode: 0o777})
```

But I get the rights to the file - 755

As I understood from the [article](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) - 0o777 this is the maximum value

Comment: A guess into the wild, this could be because only one process can write to a file at the time. Perhaps you have to do a chmod after closing the file. Stupid question, but your OS is linux/unix based or a Windows host?

Comment: @Marc On Linux - Ubuntu

Comment: The docs say `mode` is supported by this method. You might try to modify your script to create the handle and then pause for 15 seconds so you can externally inspect file permissions before the stream is closed. It's possible the file perms are changed to or from the right value during the process.

Comment: On the Unix systems there is a setting called `umask` (whose default value is `0022` or `0002`, depending the OS flavour and the admin preferences). This is used to reset some permission bits when [a file or directory is created](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/creat.2.html) (usually the write permission for group and other users). It seems that Node.js does not change the file permissions after it creates the file. You have to change them using [`fs.chmod()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fschmodpath-mode-callback) or an equivalent function.

Comment: @nicolaa just tried it and got 775, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, node v16.19.0

Comment: Thanks for the help, `fs.chmod()` helped